# Storing Spark DataFrame Value In scala Variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to Check the duplicate filename in my table and if file count is 0 then i need to load a file in my table using `sparkSql`. I wrote below code.

```scala
    val s1=spark.sql("select count(filename) from mytable where filename='myfile.csv'") //giving '2'
    s1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [count(filename): bigint]
    s1.show //giving 2 as output
```

//s1 is giving me the filecount from my table then i need to compare this count value using if statement.
I'm using below code.

```
    val s2=s1.count   //not working always giving 1
    val s2=s1.head.count() // error: value count is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    val s2=s1.size //value size is not a member of Unit
    if(s1>0){ //code } //value > is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

can someone please give me a hint how should i do this.How can i get the dataframe value and can use as variable to check the condition.
i.e.

```
    if(value of s1(i.e.2)>0){
    //my code
    }
```

Comment: you should maybe read again about what an aggregate function in SQL does and what `count` on a dataframe does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the value itself. Count will return the number of rows in the df, which is just one row.

So you can keep your original query and extract the value after with first and getInt methods

```scala
val s1 = spark.sql("select count(filename) from mytable where filename='myfile.csv'")`
val valueToCompare = s1.first().getInt(0)
```

And then:

```
  if(valueToCompare>0){
    //my code
    }
```

**Another option** is performing the count outside the query, then the count will give you the desired value:

```
val s1 = spark.sql("select filename from mytable where filename='myfile.csv'")


   if(s1.count>0){
    //my code
    }
```

I like the most the second option, but there is no reason other than that i think it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

`spark.sql("select count(filename) from mytable where filename='myfile.csv'")` returns a dataframe and you need to extract both the first row and the first column of that row. It is much simpler to directly filter the dataset and count the number of rows in Scala:

```
val s1 = df.filter($"filename" === "myfile.csv").count
if (s1 > 0) {
  ...
}
```

where `df` is the dataset that corresponds to the `mytable` table.

If you got the table from some other source and not by registering a view, use `SparkSession.table()` to get a dataframe using the instance of `SparkSession` that you already have. For example, in Spark shell the pre-set variable `spark` holds the session and you'll do:

```
val df = spark.table("mytable")
val s1 = df.filter($"filename" === "myfile.csv").count
```